# What does the "views" column in the SO schema store?

Tags: support, data-dump, data-explorer

I'm not sure what that's supposed to store! Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Number of page views maybe?

Comment: @Jon, if you look at the data dump, most people have a 0 in there... and some of the senior people on this site have a couple... it's not possible that this is page views... can it be that a founder has only 15 page views?

Comment: His page is boring.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anatomy of a data dump](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the number of user profile views. I believe these are IP-unique as well.

Most of the data in that column is 0 because there are a *lot* of users with < ~10 rep... not many people look at those kinds of profiles.

In [Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com), try:

```
SELECT Views, Id AS [User Link] FROM Users ORDER BY Views DESC
```

There *is* data there, you just need to concentrate on the most active users.